# How to make a table fixed width in FF and IE7/IE8

Tags: css, html, width, tablelayout

I'm using [this free html template](http://freehtml5templates.com/minimalism-html5-and-css3-template/) to create a page that displays some information about a web application. Please see this JsFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/wx3Gz/1/

The problem are the tables in the three columns in the main content.
I'd like to set the tables to the same width as the column (274px) each, and the content should be automatically arranged within.

For the first table I'd like to have the 2nd column to be as wide as the content requires, the first column then should take up the rest of the available width and overflow with ellipsis.

Anything I already tried (setting display: block on the table, using tabley-layout: fixed) resulted in either a table with all the columns having the same (wrong) width or in the most cases in content overflowing the column.

The perfect solution would format all tables in the three group-elements to a max width and  allow to set a css class on the columns (the th elements, that is) that should show ellipsis where the column gets to wide). An almost perfect solution would require that css class on every cell.

I need this to work in Firefox and IE7/8. Ideally also IE9 and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `max-width` on the table cells rather than on the table directly:

```
td {
    max-width: 200px;
}
td div, td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Here's a modified version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/wx3Gz/9/).  I'm not on Windows, so I can't check in IE.

Comment: That indeed works in FF and Chrome. Sadly not in IE. But that is a nice approach, so I'll try to modify from that point onwards for IE compatibility.